# Recreating the jar in Java after doing changes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, backend, war

I had to do change the source code of existing `jar`. Since we did not have source code we extracted jar using some online tool and did the changes in particular file.  Now I want to recompile before updating on the existing `jar` file.

for eg my jar name is `YahooConnectService-0.0.1.jar`

and I extracted this `jar` using online tool and I did changes in `YahooDAOImpl.java`

Now I am trying to recompile `YahooDAOImpl.java` file using below command.

```
javac -classpath YahooConnectService-0.0.1.jar C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java
```

but it is giving error. what wrong I am doing?

Do I need to change something?

```
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:37: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                                 ^
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:38: error: package org.springframework.context.support does not exist
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
                                                    ^
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YahooDAOImpl.class);
                           ^
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class YahooDAOImpl
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YahooDAOImpl.class);
                                           ^
  symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class YahooDAOImpl
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:139: error: cannot access StoredProcedure
  GetSOIDetailsStoredProcedure proc = (GetSOIDetailsStoredProcedure)getSPInstance("getSOIDetailsStoreProcedure");
                                                  ^
  class file for org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure not found
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:140: error: cannot access DataAccessException
 Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)new GetSOIInputParam());
                                                  ^
  class file for org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException not found
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:261: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

    Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                    ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:643: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

   Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:682: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

    Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                    ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:697: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

/* 697 */     Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:706: error: cannot find symbol
/* 706 */     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SOIApplicationConfig.xml");
              ^
  symbol:   class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
  location: class YahooDAOImpl
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:706: error: cannot find symbol
/* 706 */     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SOIApplicationConfig.xml");
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
  location: class YahooDAOImpl
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:710: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

/* 710 */     Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:767: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

/* 767 */     Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)input);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:814: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

/* 814 */     Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
/* 848 */     Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java:856: error: method execute in class AbstractStoredProcedure<E
cannot be applied to given types;

/* 856 */     Map<String, Object> resultMap = proc.execute((AbstractInputParameter)SOIInputDvo);
                                                  ^
  required: GetSOIInputParam
  found: AbstractInputParameter
  reason: actual argument AbstractInputParameter cannot be converted to GetSOIInputParam by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends AbstractInputParameter declared in class AbstractStoredProcedure
Note: C:\Users\uservice\dao\impl\YahooDAOImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

when same file is working inside a jar why it is not able to find libraries to get compiled.
AM I doing something wron?g

Comment: Can somebody help me on this., Please  struggling for many days.

Comment: the jar has dependencies to external libraries. If you want to compile it, you need to recreate the full structure including all dependencies which the jar was built with. Check out jar [structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html). It's also possible, that the jar is a [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) project.